# Preventing ui-router state controller reload after changing state with params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

The following angular + ui-router app:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

  // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1");

  $stateProvider
    .state("route1", {
        url: "/route1?x",
        templateUrl: "route1.html",
        controller: function($scope, $state){
          console.log("route 1");
          $scope.setUrlParam = function(p) {
            console.log("set x", p);
            $state.go('route1', {x: p}, {notify: false, location:'replace'})
          }
        }
    })
    .state('route2', {
        parent: "route1",
        url: "/route2",
        templateUrl: "route2.html",
        controller: function($scope){
          console.log("route 2");
          $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
        }
    })

})
```

...has two states, `route1` and `route2` which is a child of `route1`.

- Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3P9ZE1HvSgK24B1MrIf4?p=preview
- Click on "Live Preview" and open the console panel in your dev tools.

Clicking on "Goto route 1" and "Goto route 2" will only trigger the run of Controller 2 when changing the state to `route2` (Open the console to view) as expected.

However, my app needs to change some url params in `route1` on various occasions (for example, when a user drags the map, we would like to change the url to reflect the coordinates in the url), but nothing else should happen.  Checking out [ui-router docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state), the following is used to change the url params:

```
$state.go('route1', {x: p}, {notify: false, location:'replace'})
```

This works great (for changing the url).

However, after using this technique, using `$state.go('route2')` triggers `route1`'s controller reload!  Try clicking on "set x to 123" and then on "goto route 2" on the demo.

How can I prevent the reloading `route1`'s controller?

Any help would be appreciated!

Versions Used:

- angular 1.2.4
- ui-router 0.2.15

Comment: If you want to change url without reloading app, try $location service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add this in your state config

```
reloadOnSearch: false
```

and call the function below when you want update url

```
$location.search( { param: value } );
```

url should be able to update without reloading

hope this helps

Comment: `reloadOnSearch: false` was enough